# Code::Blocks and MPI

Tags: c++, c, mpi, codeblocks

I installed Code::Blocks and MPICH2 and config my Code::Blocks like below:

- Search Directories (Compiler): C:\Program Files\MPICH2\include
- Search Directories (Linker): C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib
- Linker settings: mpi.lib

my compiler always (because of thread) have -std=c++0x option!
also I added bin dir of MPICH2 to my path. and my OS is win 7 x64.
but while I try to compile a simple hello world program I got this errors:

```
C:\Users\1111\Desktop\CPP Project\MPI\First_MPI\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `MPI_Init'|

C:\Users\1111\Desktop\CPP Project\MPI\First_MPI\main.cpp|10|undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_rank'|

C:\Users\1111\Desktop\CPP Project\MPI\First_MPI\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_size'|

C:\Users\1111\Desktop\CPP Project\MPI\First_MPI\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to `MPI_Finalize'| 

||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 36 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
and finally this is my code!
```

also my code is:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "mpi.h"
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int my_rank;
    int my_size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_size);
    cout<< "I'm rank (processor number) " << my_rank << " of " <<  my_size << "processor";
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure MPICH2 and your project of the same "bitness", i.e. both are 32-bit or both are 64-bit. Also, look into the `C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib` directory and make sure that the library is not called, e.g. `mpich.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are seeing come from your compiler not being able to find libmpich.

Do you have C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin\mpicc ?  You should use that to build your program.

If you don't have an mpicc wrapper, you need to add the mpich library to your link command.

You should consult the Code:Blocks documentation for adding a compiler.  specifically, 
http://svn.code.sf.net/p/codeblocks/code/trunk/COMPILERS gives this advice:

> If you installed the compiler on a directory other than its default,
>   launch Code::Blocks. If it is the first time you launch it, the
>   compiler will be auto-detected. If not, go to "Settings/Configure
>   plugins/Compiler", select the compiler you installed, switch to the
>   "Programs" tab and press "Auto-detect". If you get a message saying
>   that the compiler was auto-detected, congratulations! If not, then
>   press the button with the three dots next to the "Auto-detect" button
>   and select the installation directory of your compiler manually.